# Youtube Apiにてコミュニティのコメントを取得したい

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

Youtube Apiにてコミュニティのコメントを取得したいです。 動画からのコメントは取得できるのですがコミュニティに関しては記載が見当たらず困っています。
もしご存じでしたらご回答お願い致します。